# (1Gb RAM) very slow and freezes often on 11.10

Tags: 11.10

my Netbook ist very slow with 11.10. Windows often freeze. I have a Samsung N150 with 1Gb RAM and 1.5Gb swap. Ram appears to be constantly filled. All I have opened is the browser. Here is what I get after free -m:

```
              total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:           988        887        101          0         16        343
-/+ buffers/cache:        526        461
Swap:         1429        238       1191
```

Please help. This is very annoying.

Comment: can you post the output of `top -n 1`

Answer (score 1):

If you only have 1GB of RAM and you want to maintain decent performance, you might want to disable the new flashy interface, because that can be a load on resources. Here are a couple simple ways of doing this:

1. When you login from the main login screen, select the gear (top right corner of the selected account box), and change from "Ubuntu" to "Ubuntu 2D"
2. If that doesn't slow things down enough, you can easily [remove Unity completely](http://linux-software-news-tutorials.blogspot.com/2011/10/ubuntu-1110-oneiric-remove-unity-and.html) and use the original GNOME desktop.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I follow both of your suggestions. It didn't really helped. Ram still appears to be completely filled having only the browser opened. Is it that my hardware is to weak, or does it have something to do with the compiz stuff? Please help. To make things worse, after following through the second point, usual Alt-Shortcuts do not work (Alt+F4 etc.) and windows do not respond to keyboard input. This is awful. Do I have to reinstall ubuntu or is there a way of undoing this problem?

Comment: You can probably follow that backwards (switching install with remove) to go back to Unity. If the problem is only with your browser, you could try using Google Chrome instead of Firefox -- a lot of people have complained about Firefox hogging resources.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that based on the output of free -m you have plenty of available memory. Don't be confused by free which is only 100MB because modern OS try to use all available memory for buffering and caching when ever nothing else needs it. Long story short this line is what you should be looking at:

```
              total       used       free 
 -/+ buffers/cache:        526        461
```

...which means that almost half your RAM is free so your problem may be elsewere.

Comment: Yeah, but he is also using swap, which is just horrible for performance.